# how to invoke node module inside from function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a situation where i am listening messages from kafka server by creating consumer, now `consumer.on` is getting the messages from kafka now i have to send these messages to client using `socket.io` so once i receive message i have created export method that will emit the message so in below code i have exported  start method so i can start consumer and `socket.io` connection, but its throwing exception ./main require is not a function. How can i send message using `socket.io` once consumer receives it.

main.js

```
function start() {
  var consumer_client = new kafka.Client(kafkaConn, clientId);
  var client = new Client(consumer_client.connectionString, clientId);
  var consumer = new HighLevelConsumer(client, topics, options);

  startConsumer(consumer);
};

function startConsumer(consumer) {
  consumer.on('message', function(message) {
    logger.log('info', message.value);
    exports = module.exports = function(io) {
      io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.emit('ditConsumer', message.value);
      });
    }
  });
  consumer.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('error', err);
  });
};

exports.start = start;
```

app.js

```
var ditconsumer = require('./main');

server.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
  Producer.startProducer();
  ditconsumer.start();
});
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: its throwing error ditconsumer is not a function

Comment: You are replacing the export in your code when run startConsumer function. Instead of that, try to just extend exports with new property.
I mean exports.startConsumer = function(io)....

Comment: @hussain That's because you aren't only exporting a function. You're exporting an object with a property of `start`. You would need to call `ditconsumer.start` and then you're doing some weird stuff with the exports in that function...

Comment: i am new to nodejs, any better way to implement this i will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Wish this work for you:

**main.js:**

```
    var Consumer = {
        start:function(scfun) {
              var consumer_client = new kafka.Client(kafkaConn, clientId);
              var client = new Client(consumer_client.connectionString, clientId);
              var consumer = new HighLevelConsumer(client, topics, options);
              consumer.on('message', function(message) {
                logger.log('info', message.value);
                scfun(message.value);
              });
              consumer.on('error', function(err) {
                console.log('error', err);
              });         
            };

    };
    module.exports = Consumer;
```

**app.js:**

```
var ditconsumer = require('./main');

io.sockets.on('connection',function(){      
    Producer.startProducer();  
    ditconsumer.start(function(value){
     io.emit('ditConsumer',value)
    });
});

server.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');  
});
```